# How to store different type and number of fields in one database table?

Tags: laravel

Hello everybody I'm making a "Bulletin board", like this: http://stena.kg/ad/post, I'm using Laravel 5.0, and don't know how to store different fields in database table, for example if I choose "Cars" category I should to fill Mark, Model, Fuel (etc fields for cars category), If I choose Flats category I should fill fields like Area, Number of rooms etc...How to organize all of this? I tried some ideas but nothing helped me(

Answer (score 0):

Try to save data as json in table. Parse json format to string and save it in db, but it will cause many problems in future, so not recommend that solution. I recommend to store data in separate tabels, each one for category. For optimise process it is possible to create catregory table, and category_item table with fields like name, description and so on. Different category demands sp=ecific fields, so best solution is to create table per category.

Comment: Ok, I guess, it's good idea and I will use it, but where to store information about fields witch belongs to category? (example, Car model field belongs to Cars category, Area field belongs to Flats category) I have already created different tables for categories but now I have some problems, for example I have flats, houses and lands tables all of them have different fields but also I need to search throw this three tables, it's not very easy. And if I will have much categories I have to create very much tables in my db and models in my application. It's not very good(